# Program to find the maximum average out of given records. Input mismatch exception. string value goes null

Tags: java

Program to find the maximum average out of given records. Input mismatch exception. string value became blank while iterating over for loop value i=1

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaxAvg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Records> rec = new ArrayList<Records>();
        int maxAvg = 0, maxIndex = 0;
        String s ="";

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            s = sc.nextLine();
            int m1 = sc.nextInt();
            int m2 = sc.nextInt();
            int m3 = sc.nextInt();
            rec.add(new Records(s,m1,m2,m3));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            int avg = (rec.get(i).m1 + rec.get(i).m2 + rec.get(i).m3 )/3;
            if(avg > maxAvg)
            {
                maxAvg = avg;
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(rec.get(maxIndex).name  + "   " + maxAvg);

    }

}



class Records
{
    String name;
    int m1,m2,m3;
    public Records(String name, int m1, int m2, int m3) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.m1 = m1;
        this.m2 = m2;
        this.m3 = m3;
    }
}
```

this is the exception i am encountering

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at MaxAvg.main(MaxAvg.java:19)
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html

Comment: print value of s and check the value
read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Answer (score 0):

java.util.InputMismatchException :-

Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

Did you type in something that wasn't an int?

Comment: No the inputs were correct

Comment: @yogaranjan - The issue is that your `nextInt()` leaves behind a new line character that is taken up by nextLine()`. Go through the question used to mark your question as dupe